# use HTTPS for specific actions in grails

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm using **spring-security-core:2.0-RC5** Grails plugin , i searched on how to force the browser to use HTTPS on specific application's pages i found the below configuration :

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.auth.forceHttps = true
 grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.definition = [
 '/login/**':         'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL'
  ]
```

when i apply this in the config, and try access the login page, it shows me `this page can't be displayed` , and the protocol is still `HTTP` ,i know there is a way to run the whole application on`HTTPS` by using `grails run-app -https` but what i need to achieve is to force some pages to use `HTTPS` , is there a way to make this ?

Comment: any ideas about this issue?

Comment: I think filters is the way to go. http://techdem.centerkey.com/2013/08/grails-filter-redirect-http-to-https.html?m=1

Comment: I moved the post about filters to: https://blog.centerkey.com/2013/08/grails-filter-redirect-http-to-https.html